# Moving money between users

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, authorize.net, stripe-connect

Need your help figuring out this. I am trying to achieve the following:

**Scenario**:

1. My app charges User A $10
2. My app takes $0.20 from $10.
3. My app credits User B with $9.80-(any payment gateway charges)

So basically my app is moving money from User A to B.

*One another important aspect* - **I don't want to store credit card information.**

What would be the best(and least expensive) way to achieve this?

Stripe, Paypal, etc?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Stripe connected accounts. It makes sure we're tax compliant working with our contractors. We make them each their own managed Stripe account. We create credit card tokens through Stripe's API, and attach them to the Stripe customer token for our users. We never handle the data on our own server, but Stripe does store it on their user object, fully PCI compliant.

Their fees are industry standard, and until you start processing larger volumes, are non-negotiable by anyone. As you reach larger milestones ($1M / yr), you may be able to start negotiating better rates. Keep in mind that .01% of a $50.00 transaction is still only $0.05, so depending on your average transaction size, negotiating the constant taken out as a fee is more often the most beneficial thing you can do, rather than negotiating the 2.9% processing fee down.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I will look into Stripe Connect

Comment: No problem.

One thing I'll note, a lot of people see that there is no way around that 2.9% + $0.30 fee, and get the idea that they'll just spend some time building their own payment platform to avoid it. DON'T DO THIS!! That takes a team of highly skilled and experienced engineers a long time, and opens you up to all sorts of law suits for potential security risks. Just don't even consider it an option. It isn't feasible for a startup, or even many large companies.

Comment: That makes sense. You are right on money. And thanks again for taking the time.